# Multiple Counters C# - How to mimic in VBA? j = i++

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am trying to understand what the following loop is saying so that I can convert this to VBA:

```
for ( int i = 0, j = polygon.Length - 1 ; i < polygon.Length ; j = i++ )
```

What is the equivalent of j=i++ in VBA? I don't even really understand what j=i++ is even saying. I understand i++ on its own would act similar to i=i+1 but I am lost with assignment of j being tied to an increase in i. I have the following thus far but I'm not sure how to account for the j variable.

```
Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer
i = 0
j= polygon.length - 1

Do While i < polygon.Length
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way of typing your loop but perhaps in an easier to read way.

```
j = polygon.Length - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < polygon.Length; i++)
{
    // do whatever is inside the for loop
    j = i;
}
```

So to answer your question

```
Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer
i = 0
j= polygon.length - 1

Do While i < polygon.Length
    j = i
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: So the j=i++ states that j should be equal to the current value of i before it is incremented?

Comment: Correct. `++` is a postfix operator meaning that the increment happens after the statement is evaluated. Likewise, if it was `j = ++i' then j would always equal i.